# Distance between nodes in a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, distance

This must be a recursive algorithm

`dis(tree, x, y)` <--function call
x & y are nodes

each recursive calls returns (dx, dy, dxy)
dx is depth of x
dy is depth of y
dxy is distance from each other

I'm thinking using lowest common ancestor, but that doesn't suit this format (no global variables).

Comment: just need an idea of what needs to be done at each stack frame

Comment: Why do you need global variables for LCA?  Also, are you sure that LCA would help you here?

Comment: I'm thinking once I get the LCA, I just need to find the distance of x from LCA and distance of y from LCA, and add together if they are on different sides of LCA, or subtract if they are on same

Comment: @user1419501- But how does this require global variables?

Comment: you'll need an ancestor list for x AND y and that must be declared as global

Comment: @user1419501- That data does not need to be global.  You could create a wrapper function that declares this information as a local variable, then passes it off to a helper function.  When the wrapper function terminates, the extra information would leave scope with it.  You absolutely do not need globals for this.

Comment: do your nodes have links to their parents?

Answer (score 3):

> This must be a recursive algorithm

I assume you mean that as a constraint on the answers you desire (there are iterative solutions).  The recursive (functional) solution is as follows:

```
dis(tree, x, x) = 0

dis(tree, x, NULL) = INF
dis(tree, NULL, x) = INF 

dis(tree, x, y) = min(dis(tree, parent(x), y)+1, dis(tree, x, parent(y))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is doubly linked, you could do a Breadth First Search from Node x searching for Node y.

Comment: You only need to find common ancestor, so only need to search (logN) ancestor lists, no need for BFS.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. In most cases, finding the common ancestor is much faster than a BFS. My apologies.